# Sorting array of dictionaries by number

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting

So I have an array with about 180 dictionaries, There are 5 objects in each dictionary (3 strings and 2 NSNumbers)

I am trying to sort each dictionary by one of its properties, this works fine for the strings but when it comes to the number it does not sort correctly.

```
 -(void) sortArrayBy:(int)sortingNumber {

    switch (sortingNumber) {
            case 0:
                NSLog(@"sorting by atomicnumber");
                [self.elementsArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
 // When sorting this comes back the same each time but not in the correct order
                [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"ATOMIC NUMBER" ascending:YES], nil]];
                break;
            case 1:
                NSLog(@"sorting by name");
                [self.elementsArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"ELEMENT NAME" ascending:YES], nil]];
                break;
            case 2:
                NSLog(@"sorting by symbol");
                [self.elementsArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"CHEMICAL SYMBOL" ascending:YES], nil]];
                break;
            case 3:
                NSLog(@"sorting by mass");
 // When sorting this comes back the same each time but not in the correct order
                [self.elementsArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"ATOMIC MASS" ascending:YES], nil]];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Care to clarify "consistent but not correct", please? '1, 20, 3', for example, is "constitent *and* correct" for certain applications.

Comment: Could you give an example of "consistent but incorrect" sorting? Show us a sub-sequence after the sort, and point out the out-of-order items.

Comment: I mean each time I sort it it comes back the same but the order is incorrect

Comment: @user2113952 Is there any pattern to that incorrect order, though? Could you show, say, the first ten..fifteen numbers after the sort?

Comment: I can't see any pattern in the sort

Comment: There are like sections of it where the numbers are in order but then the sections are out of order if that makes sense

Answer (score 4):

Ok so I figured out the problem, it was sorting by the first number not the whole number for some reason, so i use this code:

```
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor 

sortDescriptorWithKey:@"ATOMIC MASS" ascending:YES comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
                return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
            }];

            [self.elementsArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: sortDescriptor, nil]];
```

Comment: It was sorting the numbers "alphabetically", meaning that 100 will sort before 2.

Comment: That is *exactly* what my comment inferred. A short example list of 'badly sorted' data would have shown it immediately.